# Use the jQuery load() function to get the grandparent of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

An HTML page (which I can't edit) contains a table from which I want to extract all rows where the first td contains a child element with the class "**targetClass**".

For example, the table contains:

```
<tr>
  <td><span class="targetClass">Dog</span></td>
  <td>
    <p>Man's best friend.</p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cat</td>
  <td>
    <p>Mouse's worst enemy.</p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><span class="targetClass">Mouse</span></td>
  <td>
    <p>Timid cheese-loving creature.</p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In this example I want the first and third tr.

So I currently have a Javascript file that uses the jQuery load() function to go to this target page and grab all the spans with the class "**targetClass**" and put them in a div on the page from which the Javascript is called. My Javascript is:

```
var newElement = $('<div>').load(url + ' .targetClass', function(response, status, xhr) {
    ... 
    alert(newElement.html());
    ... 
});
```

The alert box shows a set of spans. But what I want it to do is to get the grandparent tr element for each of those spans.

I want the selector in the first parameter of the load() function to do this:

```
$(".targetClass").parent().parent()
```

I tried using this as the selector. It doesn't work.

Anyone know how, rather than getting the element with the specified class, I can get its grandparent?

Comment: I don't think its possible with `.load` this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get()`, and  it inserts the content automagically, if you need to get the elements with complicated selectors or into variables, you should just use `$.get` instead

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    var newElement   = $('<div />'),
        grandparents = $(data).find(".targetClass").closest('tr');

    newElement.append(grandparents);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works. Not sure whether yours or Amit Joki's solution is the best. Much appreciated.

Comment: This was the solution I chose to you. Marking this one accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the opposite way. Instead of matching `.targetClass` and then going up, match `tr` and go down.

```
var newElement = $('<div>').load(url + ' tr:has(.targetClass)', function() {
    alert(newElement.html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
var newElement = $('<div>').load(url, function() {
    var o = '';
    var trs = newElement.find('tr').each(function(){
                 o += $(this).find('.targetClass').closest('tr')[0].outerHTML;
              });
    alert(o);
});
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain how that works, so the rest of us gets it ?

Comment: Hmm...seems confusing to me too now.

Comment: Especially the part where you filter based on outerHTML is very confusing, as filter expects a true/false return to include/exclude the element from the collection ?

Comment: @adeneo i feel this should do now, yet i feel yours and Barmars answers are better than this. suggestions are most welcome. i mean if this is possible this way anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo selector only native to jQuery.

```
var newElement = $('<div>').load(url + ' tr:has(.targetClass)', function() {
    alert(newElement.html());
});
```

Now it will only select `<tr>` if any of its descendants (not just direct child) have the class of `.targetClass`

Note that I've suggested you the above since you insisted on it. You can do the same in code

Comment: Thanks. That works. You wrote: "I've suggested you the above since you insisted on it." Sounds like there might be a better way of doing it. Yes?

Comment: glad to have helped you mate! @AlistairChristie